# Unit-speed Reparametrization of a circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

I am studying some differential Geometry from Shifrin's differential Geometry notes.

From what I understand so far it seems like it is possible to unit-speed reparametrize a curve whenever the curve is regular.

In the notes that I am reading the parametrization of the circle is:
$\alpha = (a\cos{t},a\sin{t}), \implies \lVert \alpha '(t)\rVert = a$

And then it is mentioned that if we reparametrize the curve by

$\beta(s) = (a\cos(s/a),a\sin(s/a)) \implies \lVert\beta'(s)\rVert=1$

So my question how did the author derive that this exact reparametrization have unit speed?, He could impossibly just have guessed it..

And is there any General way to find a unit speed reparametrization of a parametrized curve?

Comment: When dealing with a problem involving a simple curve like this, it's probably better to use simple algebra and geometry than calculus. And since the circle has uniform speed, you could just treat it as a line segment of length $2\pi a$ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is at the top of p. 8 of my notes. In the case of the circle as originally parametrized, the arclength, starting at $t=0$, is $s(t)=at$. So $t=s/a$. Thus, $\beta(s) = \alpha(s/a) = \big(a\cos(s/a),a\sin(s/a)\big)$ is a reparametrization by arclength. You can immediately check that $\|\beta'(s)\|=1$, but the general argument is in the notes there.

Comment: Now this might be a silly question, but when taking the derivative of a unit-speed reparametrization curve, do we just get 0?

Comment: No, you get the unit tangent vector along the curve. That's sort of the whole point, as you'll see in the next section.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of a parametrization $r$ is given by $|r'|$ by definition. Intuitively you can think of it in this way: if you visualize your curve in space and assume $t$ to represent time then $r(t+ \Delta t)-r(t)$ is the vector that takes the points on the curve $r(t)$ at time $t$ to the point on the curve $\Delta t$ time later, which is $r(t+ \Delta t)$. If you divide this by $\Delta t$ you obtain a vector  $\frac{r(t+ \Delta t)-r(t)}{\Delta t}$ whose norm is just "distance" between two points divided by the time it takes to go from one to anoher. By making $\Delta t$ very small and by taking the norm one obtains the so called speed of the parametrization.

You can look for unitary speed parametrized curves at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Length_and_natural_parametrization

Comment: Sorry my question was stated unclearly... I edited to how did the author know that this exact reparametrization have unit speed

Comment: It's the definition of derivatives of functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ : $\beta ' (s) = ( \beta_1'(s), \beta_2'(s) ) = (-a \frac{1}{a} \sin(s/a), a \frac{1}{a}  \cos(s/a))$. Now if you compute the norm it's $1$